# Return closest temperature to zero in C# language

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got asked the following question to program and below is the code I created.  Is there a better way to do it?  Thanks,

Implement the method ClosestToZero to return the temperature closer to zero which belongs to the array ts.

•   If ts is empty, return 0 (zero)

•   If two numbers are as close to zero, consider the positive integer as the closer to zero (eg. -5 and 5, return 5)
Input:

•   Temperatures are always expressed with floating point numbers ranging from `-273 to 5526`

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] ts = { 7, 12, -2, 8, 1 };
            var result = closetozero(ts);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        public static double closetozero(double[] ts)
        {
            int targetNumber = 0;
            var nearest = ts.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - targetNumber)).First();
            return nearest;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Defiee a "better" way.

Comment: Better way to code it.

Comment: Belongs on Code Review but that's not an option on the close menu

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: What's with all of the casting? Why not just work in `double` the whole time?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static double ClosestToZero(double[] ts)
{

    if(ts == null || ts.LongLength ==0 )
        return 0;

    double a = ts[0];
    double b;
    for(int i = 0; i <= ts.LongLength-1; i++){
        if(Math.Abs(a) > Math.Abs(ts[i])){
            a = ts[i];
        }
        else if(Math.Abs(a) == Math.Abs(ts[i]))
        {  
            a = a > ts[i] ? a : Maths.Abs(ts[i]); 
        }
    }

    return a;

}
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation to your code? Code-only answers aren't really well-received on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As Sweeper said, define "better".

In terms of runtime:  Ditch the LINQ, write out the loop.  The thing is your approach builds a list of values and then sorts them (O(n log n).  A simple loop does no memory allocation and runs in O(n) time.

Also, it doesn't look to me like +5 is favored over -5 in your code, making it categorically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        string[] inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int closest=0;
        if(n>0)
        {
          closest=int.Parse(inputs[0]);
          for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
          {
            int t = int.Parse(inputs[i]); 
            if(Math.Abs(closest-0)>Math.Abs(t-0))
            {closest=t;}
            else if(Math.Abs(closest-0) == Math.Abs(t-0))
            {
                if(closest-Math.Abs(closest)==0 && t-Math.Abs(t)==0)
                {closest=closest;}
                else if(closest-Math.Abs(closest)==0)
                {closest=closest;}
                else if(t-Math.Abs(t)==0)
                {closest=t;}
            }
         }
       }
          Console.WriteLine(closest);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A "better" way would be to use `ForEach` and store the closest to zero as you go, taking +/- into consideration. There is no reason to sort the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static double closetozero(double[] ts)
{
    return ts.Aggregate((t1, t0) => Math.Abs(t1) > Math.Abs(t0) ? t0 : t1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int ComputeClosestToZero(int[] ts)
    {
        // Write your code here
        // To debug: Console.Error.WriteLine("Debug messages...");
        if (ts == null || ts.Length == 0)
            return 0;
        if (ts.Length == 1)
            return ts[0];
        if (ts.Length == 2 )
            return ts[0]>=ts[1] ? ts[0] :ts[1];

        int a = ts[0];
        bool b = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <= ts.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (ts[i] > 0 && a > 0)
            {
                b = true;
                if (ts[i] == 1)
                    return ts[i];
                if (a > ts[i])
                {
                    a = ts[i];
                }
               
            }
            else if(!b)
            {
                if (ts[i] == -1)
                    return ts[i];
                if (a < ts[i])
                {
                    a = ts[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
public static double ClosestToZero(double[] ts)
{

    if(ts == null || ts.LongLength ==0 )
        return 0;

    double a = ts[0];
    double b;
    for(int i = 0; i <= ts.LongLength-1; i++){
        if(Math.Abs(a) > Math.Abs(ts[i])){
            a = ts[i];
        }
        else if(Math.Abs(a) == Math.Abs(ts[i]))
        {  
            a = a > ts[i] ? a : ts[i];
        }
    }

    return a;

}
```